# Backward and forward buttons on the browser

Tags: php

My localhost works as expected when any links are clicked; however, when i click backward button on the browser, the website is loading the page like forever. I have seen it in many websites. What is causing it? Every scripts starts with the following;

```
<?php include "base.php"; 
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('Location: index.php');
    exit();
}?>
```

Do you think the reason is about my codes or about localhost?
Thanks

Comment: Is this run on your index.php too?

Comment: Is there a `session_start()` in base.php?

Comment: Yes,there is session_start() in base.php

Comment: Do you think that i should delete session_start() in base.php and add it seperately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this piece of code is executed on your `index.php` and `$_SESSION['username']` is not set, you end up in a loop of endless redirects. Which would look like 'loading forever'.